# Mouse scroll wheel is in a direction opposite to Windows

Tags: 11.10, mouse-scroll

I am using both Windows 7 and Ubuntu Oneiric. The direction of mouse wheel scrolling is opposite for Windows and Oneiric. For example, for Oneiric, I need to roll the wheel up to scroll down a page. How can this be reset? I believe this is not the default setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the problem is now solved. I used the tip suggested in the following link: http://maketecheasier.com/reverse-mouse-scrolling-direction-in-ubuntu/:

I created a file called `~/.Xmodmap` with the following contents:

```
pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

I also tried using the naturalscrolling application, but I have been unable to get it to work so far. So maybe after all, @tiempjuuh's suggestion could also possibly work.

Answer (score 0):

[Download Natural Scrolling for Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/07/reverse-natural-scrolling-ubuntu-os-lion/)

Add ppa:zedtux/naturalscrolling to your Software Sources, update, then install the ‘naturalscrolling’ package from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Launch the applet using the Dash, and toggle Natural Scrolling using the Application Indicator present in the top panel. When Natural Scrolling is active a small ‘tick’ will be shown. Click again to disable it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 12.10 I found that the '5 4' switch had already been made, presumably upon installation.  This vexed me, so I reversed the '5 4' to '4 5' in the .Xmodmap file and things are back the way I like them.

Come to think of it, this only began to vex me at some point earlier this year.  Perhaps something I installed also installed the .Xmodmap file?

The maketecheasier article instructed me to simply clobber the .Xmodmap file before even looking at it.  I did it the careful way and it helped.

Comment: In what context does this answer to question posted by the OP? Can you please make it more relevant and directed at it? Seems like you had a similar issue, but without further information it is a bit confusing. Remember, Ask Ubuntu is not a forum and the answers are is reserved for answers relevant to the OP question.